# Create record with hasMany relationship

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

How can you create a record with a `hasMany` relationship with Ember-Data? This is my code so far:

```
var project = store.createRecord('project', {
    name: 'foo',
    organization: organizationModel,
    managers: [userModel]
});
```

The `organization` relationship gets filled in just fine, but the `managers` relationship is always empty. I've also tried using an `Ember.Set()` instead of an array, same issue. I've also tried leaving the `managers` property out of the hash, and doing this instead:

```
project.set('managers', [userModel]);
```

That didn't work either an array or a set. How exactly am I supposed to fill in the hasMany relationship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's async

```
var project = store.createRecord('project', {
    name: 'foo',
    organization: organizationModel,
});

project.get('managers').then(function(managers){
  managers.pushObject(userModel);
});
```

if not

```
var project = store.createRecord('project', {
    name: 'foo',
    organization: organizationModel,
});

project.get('managers').pushObject(userModel);
```

Comment: That was my issue, thank you. This asynchronous stuff is kind of getting out of hand. I'd rather just deal with threads.